# What are Bhakti Sutras? How many Bhakti Sutras are there?

Tags: scripture, bhakti, sutra

I have heard of Narada Bhakti Sutra and Shandilya Bhakti Sutra. These are canonical Sanskrit treatizes on Bhakti Marga (Devotional Path). How many Bhakti Sutras are there?

I have also doubt about how to categorize Bhakti Sutras? I mean, in which category do these texts belong? For example, in Vaishnava tradition, the Agamic texts (Vaishnava Samhitas) are essential. Do Bhakti Sutras part of Samhitas? Or Bhakti Sutras form a separate branch?